# R GGplot - County choropleth map - How to outline states/counties with no data?

Tags: r, ggplot2, choropleth

I am trying to make a choropleth map and it works well except for two concerns

1 - The states are not outlined differently than counties making it hard to tell where one ends and another starts

2 - Not all counties had data, so the plot has lots of blank spots. Is there an easy way to give missing ones an outline?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(urbnmapr)
library(urbnthemes)
library(janitor)

set_urbn_defaults(style = "map")

broadband <- readr::read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2021/2021-05-11/broadband.csv') %>% 
  clean_names()

broadband <- broadband %>% 
  right_join(counties, by = "county_name")

broadband %>% 
  drop_na(broadband_availability_per_fcc) %>%
  mutate(broadband_availability_per_fcc = case_when(
      broadband_availability_per_fcc == "-" ~ "0.00",
      TRUE ~ broadband_availability_per_fcc
    ),
    broadband_availability_per_fcc = as.double(broadband_availability_per_fcc)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(long, lat, group = group, fill = broadband_availability_per_fcc)) +
    geom_polygon(color = "#ffffff", size = .25) +
    coord_map(projection = "albers", lat0 = 39, lat1 = 45)
```

[image]

Here are some more attempts I tried:

```
states_sf <- get_urbn_map(map = "states", sf = TRUE)
counties_sf <- get_urbn_map(map = "counties", sf = TRUE)

broadband

broadband_map <- broadband %>% 
  inner_join(counties_sf, by = "county_name")

# Works without geom_sf county data
broadband_map %>% 
  drop_na(broadband_availability_per_fcc) %>% 
  mutate(broadband_availability_per_fcc = case_when(
    broadband_availability_per_fcc == "-" ~ "0.00",
    TRUE ~ broadband_availability_per_fcc),
  broadband_availability_per_fcc = as.double(broadband_availability_per_fcc)) %>% 
  ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data = states_sf, fill = NA, color = "black", size = 0.25) +
    # geom_sf(mapping = aes(fill = broadband_availability_per_fcc), color = NA) +
    coord_sf(datum = NA)

# Does not work when adding county level data
broadband_map %>% 
  drop_na(broadband_availability_per_fcc) %>% 
  mutate(broadband_availability_per_fcc = case_when(
    broadband_availability_per_fcc == "-" ~ "0.00",
    TRUE ~ broadband_availability_per_fcc
    ),
    broadband_availability_per_fcc = as.double(broadband_availability_per_fcc)) %>% 
  ggplot() +
    geom_sf(mapping = aes(fill = broadband_availability_per_fcc), color = NA) +
    geom_sf(data = states_sf, fill = NA, color = "black", size = 0.25) +
    coord_sf(datum = NA)
```

Answer (score 0):

I reran the code without

```
set_urbn_defaults(style = "map")
```

and noticed that the unmapped counties WERE being mapped.

The solution was to change the color from #fff... in geom_polygon to "black", or anything that does not blend into the background, and it worked!